# add XML tag to SOAP message with XSLT if tag doesn't exist

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, soap, azure-api-management

I'm quite new to XSLT and have no clue how to find a solution for my desired transformation. 
We receive a SOAP request and need to check if a certain tag (Steps) exists. If not present I want to add it to the SOAP message.

We are running the interface on Azure API Management which allows XSLT only in version 1.0.

**XML example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <ProductionToSupply xmlns="http://somenamespace.com">
      <ProductionDataList>
         <ProductionData>
            <Material_Number>5</Material_Number>
            <Doc_Number>1234</Doc_Number>
            <Description>abcde</Description>
         </ProductionData>
      </ProductionDataList>
   </ProductionToSupply>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
xmlns:ns1="http://somenamespace.com" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:ProductionToSupply/ns1:ProductionDataList/ns1:ProductionData/ns1:Doc_Number">
<xsl:if test="not(soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:ProductionToSupply/ns1:ProductionDataList/ns1:ProductionData/ns1:Steps)">
    <Steps xmlns="http://somenamespace.com">NA</Steps>
</xsl:if>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**desired output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <ProductionToSupply xmlns="http://somenamespace.com">
      <ProductionDataList>
         <ProductionData>
            <Material_Number>5</Material_Number>
            <Doc_Number>1234</Doc_Number>
            <Description>abcde</Description>
            <Steps>NA</Steps>
         </ProductionData>
      </ProductionDataList>
   </ProductionToSupply>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The expected result would be to only add the tag "Steps" if it is not present in group "ProductionData", but I don't know how to set the appropriate match pattern.

Thanks in advance for your help
tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the group `ProductionData` only if it doesn't have a `Steps` element, the template match would be this

```
 <xsl:template match="ns1:ProductionData[not(ns1:Steps)]">
```

You could then copy the `ProductionData` element and its child node, and slip in the `Steps` element at the same time

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
xmlns:ns1="http://somenamespace.com" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:ProductionData[not(ns1:Steps)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <Steps xmlns="http://somenamespace.com">NA</Steps>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would add the `Steps` as the last child. If you wanted it immediately after `Doc_Number`, replace the template with this

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:ProductionData[not(ns1:Steps)]/ns1:Doc_Number">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <Steps xmlns="http://somenamespace.com">NA</Steps>
</xsl:template>
```